# NMinimize::bcons when making the conditions only slightly more complex

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do (global) integer constrained optimization using `NMinimize`. I have some polynomial consisting of many variables $x_{1,1}...x_{5,8}$ and a couple of constraints $A, B, ..., F$. I am having problems with a particular constraint. Unfortunately I am not able to create a minimal working example, as it seems that the problem is related to the complexity of the calculation.

Let's say that

```
A = 
-800.  + x[1, 1] + x[2, 1] + x[3, 1] + x[4, 1] + x[5, 1] >= 0 && 
-500.  + x[1, 2] + x[2, 2] + x[3, 2] + x[4, 2] + x[5, 2] >= 0 && 
-2000. + x[1, 3] + x[2, 3] + x[3, 3] + x[4, 3] + x[5, 3] >= 0 && 
-5000. + x[1, 4] + x[2, 4] + x[3, 4] + x[4, 4] + x[5, 4] >= 0 && 
-1000. + x[1, 5] + x[2, 5] + x[3, 5] + x[4, 5] + x[5, 5] >= 0 && 
-6000. + x[1, 6] + x[2, 6] + x[3, 6] + x[4, 6] + x[5, 6] >= 0 && 
-1000. + x[1, 7] + x[2, 7] + x[3, 7] + x[4, 7] + x[5, 7] >= 0 && 
-4000. + x[1, 8] + x[2, 8] + x[3, 8] + x[4, 8] + x[5, 8] >= 0
```

Then, Mathematica successfully solves the problem

```
NMinimize[{Func, A && B && C && D && E && F}, Flatten@X];
```

Now, if I make the one constraint `A` more complex by allowing also `0` for each row, I am getting

> NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: ...
>   Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain
>   specifications involving the variables.

`A` then reads:

```
A = 
(x[1, 1] + x[2, 1] + x[3, 1] + x[4, 1] + x[5, 1] >= 800. || 
 x[1, 1] + x[2, 1] + x[3, 1] + x[4, 1] + x[5, 1] == 0) && 
(x[1, 2] + x[2, 2] + x[3, 2] + x[4, 2] + x[5, 2] >= 500. || 
 x[1, 2] + x[2, 2] + x[3, 2] + x[4, 2] + x[5, 2] == 0) && 
(x[1, 3] + x[2, 3] + x[3, 3] + x[4, 3] + x[5, 3] >= 2000. ||
 x[1, 3] + x[2, 3] + x[3, 3] + x[4, 3] + x[5, 3] == 0) && 
(x[1, 4] + x[2, 4] + x[3, 4] + x[4, 4] + x[5, 4] >= 5000. ||
 x[1, 4] + x[2, 4] + x[3, 4] + x[4, 4] + x[5, 4] == 0) && 
(x[1, 5] + x[2, 5] + x[3, 5] + x[4, 5] + x[5, 5] >= 1000. ||
 x[1, 5] + x[2, 5] + x[3, 5] + x[4, 5] + x[5, 5] == 0) && 
(x[1, 6] + x[2, 6] + x[3, 6] + x[4, 6] + x[5, 6] >= 6000. ||
 x[1, 6] + x[2, 6] + x[3, 6] + x[4, 6] + x[5, 6] == 0) && 
(x[1, 7] + x[2, 7] + x[3, 7] + x[4, 7] + x[5, 7] >= 1000. ||
 x[1, 7] + x[2, 7] + x[3, 7] + x[4, 7] + x[5, 7] == 0) && 
(x[1, 8] + x[2, 8] + x[3, 8] + x[4, 8] + x[5, 8] >= 4000. ||
 x[1, 8] + x[2, 8] + x[3, 8] + x[4, 8] + x[5, 8] == 0)
```

I checked that it works with the condition `A` alone, i.e., without `B...F`, so it's not syntax or anything. Also, this second version of `A` would also allow solutions of the first version. What causes my error here?

---

Edit: I tried to remove stuff from the notebook step-by-step while keeping the error. I believe the code below is a minimal working example. I hope, the error's origin really is the same as in my original problem.

```
X = Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {3, 3}];

s = {{0.3`,0.3`,1.2`},{1.2`,1.2`,0.3`},{1.4`,1.4`,1.4`}};
b = {10000.`,5000.`,10000.`};
m = {800.`,500.`,2000.`};

MinOr[xx_,mm_] = xx >= mm || xx == 0;

C1 = AllTrue[MapThread[MinOr,{Total[X,1],m}], # &];
C2 = AllTrue[Total[Transpose[X],1]-b, # == 0 &];
C3 = AllTrue[Flatten@X, # >= 0 &];
C4 = AllTrue[Flatten@X,Element[#, Integers] &];

C12 = AllTrue[Total[X, 1] - m, # >= 0 &];

NMinimize[{Total[Flatten[X*s]], C1 && C2 && C3 && C4},Flatten@X]
```

Replacing `C1` with `C12` Mathematica is able to solve it, but not with `C1`.

Comment: can you post the complete code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Please do not use MathJax for Mathematica code. Use markdown. Click on the question-mark icon at the right end of the editor toolbar to get editing help.

Comment: `E` is a protected symbol.  Try `N[E]` and see what you get or look it up in the docs. [Avoid capital single-letter variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395).

Comment: @m_goldberg: I will reformat the question tomorrow. However, all the `Subscript[]`s really make it less readable.

@happyfish: I will try again to find a working, self-contained example. Right now, it is a huge .m file, that reads parameters from external files and such.

@MichaelE2: The names I chose in this question are arbitrary, I just wanted to have as short code as possible. I am sure that I don't use any reserved names.

Comment: I have now reformatted the question and added a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica seems to choke on the fact the some of the parts of the logical expansion `C1&&C2&&C3&&C4` are pathological. In particular, when you define

```
cons = LogicalExpand[C1 && C2 && C3 && C4]
```

then

```
NMinimize[{Total[Flatten[X*s]], cons[[1]]},Flatten@X]
```

produces an error message. `cons[[1]]` is case that all `MinOr` options are set to zero. This case is clearly pathological since the combination with C3 means that all `x` must vanish. (Which may be hard for Mathematica to figure out without at total `Reduce` of the constraints.)

Mathematica's problem in this case can be circumvented by introducing a new constraint

```
C0 = AllTrue[Flatten[X], (# == 0 &)]
```

and using it explicitly resolve the pathological constraint:

```
NMinimize[
 {Total[Flatten[X*s]], C0||LogicalExpand[C1 && C2 && C3 && C4][[2 ;; 8]]},
 Flatten@X
]
```

It thus seems that the error is caused by a pathology in your constraints. Of course it may be that the pathology is inherit to your MWE. In that case proceeding by applying `LogicalExpand` to your complete constraints and trying to NMinimize with each toplevel `Or` statement may be useful to pin down the problem.

***Update***
If the problems are indeed caused by incompatible linear equations in your real world problem than it might help to apply the following to you constraints `cons`:

```
LogicalExpand[cons] /. A : And[_Equal, (_Equal) ..] :> Reduce[A]
```

This will try to reduce the subpart of your constraints consisting of equalities, eliminating those branches of the expanded constraints with incompatible equalities. This works for your MWE at least.

Comment: Hi mmeent, I think it really might have to do with expansion of conditions and then invalid conditions. My actual problem doesn't allow the all-zero solution. In fact, `LogicalExpand` gives a total of 256 possible logical combinations, of which many are invalid. Is there any way to tell `NMinimize` to just ignore these paths instead of finding out the valid ones and using only these?

Comment: One approach would be to run`NMinimize` with each of the 256 `Or` combinations (discarding those results with fatal errors), and then taking the smallest result.

Comment: That's what I was doing yesterday. Only about 5 gave me reasonable results, but luckily the best result was not the one where none of the `Or` conditions was zero, so I did make progress. Thank you again! I'll reward the bounty when I can.